# Cannot uninstall printer as it claims to be printing, but cannot connect to printer

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer

I am running Windows 7 fully updated on an Acer Aspire using a Intel core i5.

When I try to print to Lexmark LX1190 I get a message that I cannot connect to the printer.

When I tried to delete the printer file, I get a message which says I must wait until the printer is finished printing.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the Print Spooler service from services.msc.
Delete any print jobs in C:\Windows\System32\Spool\PRINTERS

You can also delete local printers from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers

Comment: no "spool" just 'spoolss.dll' and 'spoolssv'.  How do I get to hkey_ etc?

Comment: Type services.msc in the run command windows (windows key + R), find the print spooler service and restart it. Remove any files located in C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\